# StringVar().get() not returning string

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get the input of what page number the user wants.  They should type in a number, and click the submit button.  To test it, I just want to print whatever they typed and then close the window.  I've been following: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm as a guide, but I am stumped.

Why does

```
print(temp)
```

not print out a number to console?

right now it prints out:

```
<bound method IntVar.get of <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x000001FBC85353C8>>
```

I've cleaned up the code a little bit:

```
import sys
from file import *
from page import *
from view import View
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


class ViewGui:
def __init__(self):

    #Included in the class, but unrelated to the question:
    self._file = File("yankee.txt", 25)
    self.pages = self._file.paginate()
    self.initial_list = self.pages[0].readpage(self._file.fo)
    self.initial_string = ''.join(self.initial_list)


    # Create root
    self.root = Tk()
    self.root.wm_title("yankee.txt - page 1")
    # Create frame for buttons
    self.bframe = Frame(self.root)
    self.bframe.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
    self.tbutton = tk.Button(self.bframe, text="Top", command=lambda a="top": self.clicks(a)).pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)
    self.bbutton = tk.Button(self.bframe, text="Bottom", command=lambda a="bottom": self.clicks(a)).pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)
    self.ubutton = tk.Button(self.bframe, text="Up", command=lambda a="up": self.clicks(a)).pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)
    self.dbutton = tk.Button(self.bframe, text="Down", command=lambda a="down": self.clicks(a)).pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)
    self.pbutton = tk.Button(self.bframe, text="Page", command=lambda a="page": self.pageclicks()).pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)
    self.qbutton = tk.Button(self.bframe, text="Quit", command=quit).pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)
    # Create and pack Text
    self.T = Text(self.root, height=35, width=60, wrap=NONE)
    self.T.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
    # Create and pack Scrollbar
    self.S = Scrollbar(self.root, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self.T.xview)
    self.S.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
    # Attach Text to Scrollbar
    self.T.insert('1.0', self.initial_string)
    self.T.config(xscrollcommand=self.S.set, state=DISABLED)
    self.S.config(command=self.T.xview)

def pageclicks(self):
    print("pageClicks is getting called at least...")
    pop = Tk()
    pop.wm_title("Page Number")
    pop.label = Label(pop, text="Enter a Page Number:", width=35)
    pop.label.pack(side=TOP)
    pop.entrytext = IntVar()
    Entry(pop, textvariable=pop.entrytext).pack()
    pop.submitbuttontext = StringVar()
    Button(pop, text="Submit", command=lambda a=pop: self.submitted(a)).pack(side=LEFT, pady=5, padx=40)
    pop.cancelbuttontext = StringVar()
    Button(pop, text="Cancel", command=pop.destroy).pack(side=LEFT, pady=5, padx=40)

def submitted(self, a):
    print('submitted is getting called')
    temp = (a.entrytext.get)
    print(temp)

def clicks(self, a):
    print("you clicked clicks with the " + a)
    self.root.wm_title(self._file.filename + " - Page " + self._file.buttonHandler(a))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    vg = ViewGui()
    vg.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could place your complete code since I have tried the code and I have had no problems.

Comment: added the other class, and tried to make it somewhat readable.

Comment: You could place a code that reproduces the error and can be tested

Comment: There are many issues with your code. You can not go any further with the actual design. About that `pbutton`: look how you implemented `pageclicks()`

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Thank you for taking the time to look, I don't really understand your suggestions though, if you even made one.

Comment: self._file = File("yankee.txt", 25) ????

Comment: yankee.txt, 25 are simulating cmd line arguments that can be passed in, but are not related to the question.  I can edit those out if it is easier.

Comment: Did you try calling the method?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the method: submitted() is being called by clicking the submit button.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Did you read your output?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  I posted the output at the top of the question.  If you're asking if there is other output, then no, there isn't.

Comment: Yes, but have you *read* it?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams if you have helpful input or constructive criticism, by all means I'd love to hear it.  If you are going to ask vague questions and waste my time, then no thanks.  Obviously yes I read it but didn't very well understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new window you should not use `Tk()`, you must use `tk.Toplevel()`

Must change:

```
pop = Tk()
```

to

```
pop = tk.Toplevel()
```

You should also use `get()`, not just `get`. Must change:

```
temp = (a.entrytext.get)
```

to

```
temp = a.entrytext.get()
```

**Code:**

```
def pageclicks(self):
        print("pageClicks is getting called at least...")
        pop = tk.Toplevel()
        pop.wm_title("Page Number")
        pop.label = Label(pop, text="Enter a Page Number:", width=35)
        pop.label.pack(side=TOP)
        pop.entrytext = IntVar()
        Entry(pop, textvariable=pop.entrytext).pack()
        pop.submitbuttontext = StringVar()
        Button(pop, text="Submit", command=lambda a=pop: self.submitted(a)).pack(side=LEFT, pady=5, padx=40)
        pop.cancelbuttontext = StringVar()
        Button(pop, text="Cancel", command=pop.destroy).pack(side=LEFT, pady=5, padx=40)

def submitted(self, a):
    print('submitted is getting called')
    temp = a.entrytext.get()
    print(temp)
```

Comment: wowzers what a doozey.  thanks for sticking this one out.  the code you posted is working for me.  It was that get() that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Made changes to these two methods and now it is working.

```
def pageclicks(self):
    print("pageClicks is getting called at least...")
    pop = Tk()
    pop.wm_title("Page Number")
    pop.label = Label(pop, text="Enter a Page Number:", width=35)
    pop.label.pack(side=TOP)
    pop._entry = Entry(pop)
    pop._entry.pack()
    pop._entry.focus_set()
    Button(pop, text="Submit", command=lambda a=pop: self.submitted(a)).pack(side=LEFT, pady=5, padx=40)
    Button(pop, text="Cancel", command=pop.destroy).pack(side=LEFT, pady=5, padx=40)

def submitted(self, _pop):
    temp = _pop._entry.get()
    print(temp)
    _pop.destroy()
```